# OpenERP & Python Tools for Visual Studio compile error

Tags: python, odoo, ptvs

I'm trying to get the OpenERP server to build and run in Visual Studio 2012 using Python Tools for Visual Studio.

At the moment I get more than 2300 error messages, mostly along the lines of:

```
unexpected token 'x1'
```

I've downloaded the openerp-server-6.0.4 source and created a new Python project from Existing Python Code project in VS. I've selected the path to the OpenERP source(C:\OpenERP\Bin) when prompted and the file to execute when F5 is pressed is openerp-server.py. I've selected the Python 64-bit 3.3 interpreter.

The project is created, but even before building I receive the numerous unexpected token errors. For example in the account.py file it complain about an unexpected token 'tax' in the following code:

```
 tax.type=='code':
            address = address_id and obj_partener_address.browse(cr, uid, address_id) or None
            localdict = {'price_unit':cur_price_unit, 'address':address, 'product':product, 'partner':partner}
            exec tax.python_compute in localdict
            amount = localdict['result']
            data['amount'] = amount
```

When using TOOLS > Python Tools > Execute Project in Python Interactive I see the following result:

Python interactive window.  Type $help for a list of commands.

Resetting execution engine

Interactive window is not yet started.

Running C:\temp\openerp-server-6.0.4\bin\openerp-server.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\temp\openerp-server-6.0.4\bin\openerp-server.py", line 64, in 
    import tools

File "C:\temp\openerp-server-6.0.4\bin\tools__init__.py", line 23, in 
    import win32

ImportError: No module named 'win32'

Can anyone guide me into getting OpenERP to build and run using VS? Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Will you please give some detail error stack. It will help to understand problem.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information

Answer (score 0):

You have to install

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PyOpenGL

Please try after install this module.

Comment: When I run py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.6.exe It gives an error "Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry"

Comment: Which version of python you are using?